# Union in MDX query

Tags: mdx, olap

In my time dimensions i have 2013,2014,2015.

How can i make a Union in this mdx so i get the results from this mdx for all thoose years and not only for 2014 like in the example..

```
    select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Absatz Plan], [Measures].[Umsatz Plan], [Measures].[Absatz Effektiv], [Measures].[Umsatz Effektiv]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY Crossjoin(Hierarchize({([Time].[2014], [Artikel].[All Artikels], [Markt].[All Markts])}), {[Version].[14], [Version].[16], [Version].[18]}) ON ROWS
from [Budget]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just apply `CrossJoin` twice:

```
select NON EMPTY
       {[Measures].[Absatz Plan], [Measures].[Umsatz Plan], [Measures].[Absatz Effektiv], [Measures].[Umsatz Effektiv]}
       ON COLUMNS,

       NON EMPTY
       CrossJoin(
          Crossjoin(
            {[Time].[2013], [Time].[2014], [Time].[2015]},
            {([Artikel].[All Artikels], [Markt].[All Markts])}
          ),
          {[Version].[14], [Version].[16], [Version].[18]}
       )
       ON ROWS
from [Budget]
```

I removed the `Hierarchize`, as I think it is not necessary in this context. It would order its argument by the order defined for the hierarchy in the cube. If the order of the result seems wrong, you could re-add it.

Comment: +1 @frankPI - this looks interesting: how does this differ from `x*y*z`? what does the nesting do?

Comment: @whytheq `x * y * z` is just an abbreviation of `CrossJoin(CrossJoin(x, y), z)`. They do exactly the same. `CrossJoin`, like `*`, has two arguments. And in the prefix notation with parentheses around the arguments, the nesting is more clear than in the infix notation of `*`, even if it is there in the second case as well as well. Just as the question contained `CrossJoin`, I kept that to make the solution closely matching it.

Comment: @FrankPI - cheers - my comment was not any sort of criticism just hadn't seen that syntax before and wondered if it was a new trick! as always: thanks for info.

Comment: @whytheq Did my answer sound as if I was feeling criticized? Actually, I did not.

Comment: @FrankPI - that is good - I appreciate your help a lot. Feel like I got up a level MDX-wise about a week or two back but still got a way to go yet!